# Scheme definition error(short)

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

This is part of an interpreter I am making. I keep getting this error:

```
define not allowed in an expression context in: (define ret1 (list->string wl))
```

I am using DrScheme version 371, language Standard (R5RS).

```
(define (read-command)
  (set! com '( '() ))
  (set! wl (read-as-list))
  (define ret1 (list->string wl))
  (commRead)
  ret1
 )
```

similar issue here:

```html
    (define repl(
                 lambda()
                  (display "\nUofL>")
                  (define inp (read-command))
                  (define lengtha (length com)
```

Comment: Why on Earth are you using version 371? That's almost five years old! The latest version is 6.1.1, now called [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you interpreter, it seems that definitions can only appear at the beginning of the function. You should use a `let*` instead:

```
(define (read-command)
  (let* ((com '('())) ; are you sure you didn't mean '(()) ?
         (wl (read-as-list))
         (ret1 (list->string wl)))
  (commRead ret1)))
```

For the second problem, try this:

```
(define repl
  (lambda ()
    (display "\nUofL>")
    (let ((inp (read-command))
          (lengtha (length com)))
      ; return a value here
      )))
```

As a side note, your code appears to be written in a procedural style - with all those `set!` and function calls executed for the effect. How on earth is `ret1` going to be modified if you don't pass it as a parameter to `commRead`? I'd suggest you read a good book on Scheme programming and start writing code on a more functional style, currently your code isn't idiomatic and you'll get into trouble sooner or later.

Comment: ah ok, i have a smilar issue here      (define repl(
                 lambda()
                  (display "\nUofL>")
                  (define inp (read-command))
                  (define lengtha (length com)

Comment: just did, could you help with the edited example aswell.

Comment: The solution is the same: stop using `define` inside a function and instead use `let*` at the beginning for declaring local variables.

Comment: it gives me error; let*: bad syntax (not a sequence of identifier--expression bindings) in: inp

Comment: @zero6142 ok, I edited my answer. But seriously, you _must_ read a good book or tutorial, this is basic Scheme.

Comment: thanks for the help, but it just give me a bad syntax error, the particular code, is part of a bit larger set for the definition repl let: bad syntax in: (let ((inp (read-command)) lengtha (length com)))

Comment: @zero6142 maybe you should post the whole code, but please do so in a new question. We can't help you if you don't provide all the information.

Comment: @zero6142 post a _new_ question, don't keep changing this question! and the problem with your code is that you should put all that big `cond` _inside_ the let, in the part that I marked as "return a value here" in my answer

Comment: sorry, still got the error let: bad syntax (not an identifier and expression for a binding) in: inp